# Batch travel distance calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance

How to calculate the walking distance between postcodes and destination in QGIS?

I have the following shapefiles:

- 1 layer containing the destination;
- 1 layer containing 1,000 postcodes.

I've tried `Directions to Points` in the ORS Tool set but it does not handle multi-point layers. Is there another way to calculate the walking distance?

Comment: Have you had a look at the official tutorial? https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried those options however, it will return travel cost not travel distance... Are you aware of any other tools by any chance that return the actual travel distance in the output attribute table? Thanks!

Comment: The documentation states, that, if you choose `shortest` as `path type to calculate`, you'll get a distance as output, though labeled "cost". See bottom of 7.3.2

Answer (score 2):

The [QGIS Training Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html) states that, if you choose **shortest** as path type to calculate, you'll get a **distance** as output, though labeled "cost". See bottom of 7.3.2.

-paraphrased from comments by GIS SE user [Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik)