# Isoscope, but for distance

Tags: visualisation, isochrone

An isoscope shows me how far I can get within a specific amount of time. Is there a similar visualization that shows me everything within X distance by roads of location?

If so what would be the easiest way to create my own visualizations of this type? Is there an R package which provides this, and allows me to fetch map data?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322405/batch-travel-distance-calculation-in-qgis?noredirect=1#comment524651_322405

Comment: What's the difference between an "isochone" and an "isoscope"? I've never come across "isoscope" before. The distance equivalent is sometimes called a "-shed", e.g. a ["walkshed"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walkshed). Note that a [*bikeshed*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshed) doesn't seem to follow that logic. I suspect the best term is simply "isodistance".